# Besides the point or beside the point?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Beside is the more popular usage, but I have seen many references and usages of besides, as well. Beside is a preposition, and besides can be either a preposition or an adverb.

Which would be the correct usage?

Comment: I think that use of _besides_ in the phrase _besides the point_ probably originated from a misheard instance of _beside the point_. Technically, _besides the point_ means "in addition to or aside from the point," while idiomatically _beside the point_ means "irrelevant." (Logically, _beside the point_ would seem to mean "next to the point," but that's the surprising world of idioms for you.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree entirely with Sven Yargs except that I think, 'beside the point' means to be 'off the point' rather than next to it.

Example: At the Olympics, the winners stand *on* the podium. If you stand *beside* the podium then you are off it.

**Answer**

I say that 'beside the point' is correct for the reasons given by Sven Yargs. In particular, quote - *Technically, besides the point means "in addition to or aside from the point," while idiomatically beside the point means "irrelevant."*

The following ngram backs up this choice. I notice that the alternative version appears to be there as well, however on reading the associated quotes, I see that is used in a different sense.

[Google ngram: beside the point,besides the point](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beside%20the%20point%2Cbesides%20the%20point&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeside%20the%20point%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cbesides%20the%20point%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bbesides%20the%20point%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BBesides%20the%20point%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Comment: I know the usage and meaning, I would like to know which phrasing is correct.

Comment: Okay, I'll make that more explicit.

Comment: Good use of Ngram here to convey the main point.

Comment: Google for "beside the point".

Answer (score 1):

The most basic explanation for this topic is the following;

If someone is making an argument and you understood that argument but came up with a different conclusion, then your conclusion is beside the point. In other words, your conclusion is not necessarily irrelevant, you simply missed the point. Often times a simple misunderstanding of some details or nuance. You took the same path but somehow didn't arrive on the same point.

Example:

- We should help them so we can receive rewards.
- That's beside the point of helping.

Now if you argued against someone's argument and arrived on the same conclusion, then your argument is besides the point. Most of the time, this means you're arguing semantics. Other times you simply want attention to your path that lead to the point instead of focusing on the path presented by someone else. You arrive on the same point but took a different path.

Example:

- We need to help them because we're good people.
- Isn't helping people about selflessness?
- That's besides the point of being good.

So it really depends on the context of your intention and what you're trying to convey. I hope this helps.

Comment: It is not English to say "That's beside the point of helping" and "That's besides the point of being good." They are both extremely unnatural and I find it hard to make any sense of them. The phrase is "That is beside [never "besides"] the point." 
The expression ends with the word "point". It never continues with "of VERB-ing" or "of NOUN". I think Enzovic is not native English, as is also suggested by his incorrect construction "arrive on the same point" and "arrive on the same conclusion" (change "on" to "at").